# Aligning Circles horizontally in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web

I don't have that great over bootstrap yet and cannot figure out how to properly position these circles equally under the title. Any help would be great I've tried many things. I think I've missed something stupid that I should of seen.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div id="dif1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div id="dif2"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div id="dif3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div id="dif4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#dif1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(41, 168, 224);
   padding-top: 100px;
}

#dif2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(221, 126, 81);
}

#dif3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(175, 79, 122);
}

#dif4 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(138, 166, 90);
}
```

Comment: Could you post also the HTML and a draw to explain the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Remove `padding-top: 100px;` property from `#dif1` selector

```css
#dif1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(41, 168, 224);
}

#dif2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(221, 126, 81);
}

#dif3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(175, 79, 122);
}

#dif4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(138, 166, 90);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div id="dif1"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div id="dif2"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div id="dif3"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div id="dif4"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I don't know why I didn't think of that, like forreal. Simple things like that just get past me